# Sass --watch not recompiling

Tags: css, ruby, sass, watch

Sass updates my main stylesheet `build.css` when I save changes to `build.scss`, but will not update `build.css` when I save changes to any partials, for example `_grid-settings.scss`. I essentially have to manually re-save `build.scss` each time I make a change to a partial in order for Sass to detect a change.

From my terminal:

```
Justins-MacBook-Air:ageneralist justinbrown$ sass --watch stylesheets:stylesheets
>>> Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
  write stylesheets/build.css
[Listen warning]:
  Listen will be polling for changes. Learn more at https://github.com/guard/listen#polling-fallback.
```

My directory is:

```
stylesheets/
├── base
│   └── _base.scss
├── build.css
├── build.scss
├── layout
│   └── _layout.scss
└── vendor
    ├── _grid-settings.scss
    ├── bourbon
    ├── highlight
    └── neat
```

I'm using:

- Sass 3.3.8.
- Ruby 2.0.0-p353
- OSX 10.9

I've looked through several SO posts on issues with `sass --watch` but none have helped yet to guide me to a solution.

EDIT: I'm adding my `build.scss` here just in case that's the issue:

```
@import "vendor/bourbon/bourbon";
@import "vendor/grid-settings";
@import "vendor/neat/neat";
@import "base/base";
@import "layout/layout";
```

Comment: Mb it will work with the absolute import path?

Comment: @JAre tried that, but I get the same result.

Comment: Is it possible that sass is not monitoring all of the subdirectories underneath `stylesheets`?

Comment: you can test it by adding non-partial scss file.

Comment: @JAre tried it by adding `vendor/test.scss` but still no luck. `sass --watch` processes both non-partial scss files on launch but does not update test.css with subsequent saves.

Comment: Is that the file is imported into the `build.scss` stylesheet, or in one of the imports?

Comment: @piouPiouM when I tested with `test.scss` I added `@import "vendor/test.scss";` to `build.scss`, but it was only being included in the initial compilation when launching `sass --watch`. I did find a haphazard solution below though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a satisfactory answer for me, but I ended up trying out another gem that would handle preprocessing, `guard-livereload`, and though it itself didn't work, when I came back to try `sass --watch` sass properly monitored my stylesheets directory for changes (partials included) and subsequently recompiled `build.scss`.

I'm not certain why it works now, but am guessing one of the gems installed along with guard or guard-livereload solved the issue. Perhaps `listen` or `fssm`?

Comment: The 'listen will be polling for changes' warning went away for me when I did `sudo gem install listen`. Not sure if that's what fixed the overall issue for you.

Comment: @EoghanM that seems in line with what I was seeing.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue.

I managed to fix it by deleting the SASS cache directory. I also ran `sudo gem update` to update all gems on my system.

I'm not sure which of these things fixed it or if it was a combination of the two.

Comment: It's been awhile, but I think if I had done either a the `gem update` or the `gem install listen` suggested by @EoghanM below that probably would have done the trick.

Comment: Where does the SASS cache live?

Comment: Its in a hidden folder called ".sass-cache" in the root of wherever you are compiling your SASS files.

Answer (score 4):

I had also stuck to the problem of Sass seemed wasn`t watching all file changes correctly.

***Sass*** can`t watch changes in files that are located by the path directing upwards the watching file. For example:

**Variant A (Which I had)**

```
scss/
├── base
│   └── controller1.scss
├── utils
│   └── utils.scss
└── app
    └── app.scss
```

Where app.scss is:

```
@import '../base/container1'
@import '../utils/utils'
```

compiling

> > sass --watch app/app.scss:../css/styles.css
> >
> > sass --watch app:../css

In both cases sass tracks only **app.scss** file changes, but **not** **controller1.scss** or **utils.scss**

**Variant B (solution)**

```
scss/
├── base
│   └── controller1.scss
├── utils
│   └── utils.scss
└── app.scss
```

Where app.scss:

```
@import 'base/container1'
@import 'utils/utils'
```

compiling

> sass --watch app.scss:../css/styles.css

**Variant C (solution)** also works

```
scss/
├── base
│   └── controller1.scss
├── utils
│   └── utils.scss
└── app.scss
```

Where app.scss:

```
@import 'base/container1'
```

and controller1.scss:

```
@import '../utils/utils'
// ...
```

Comment: Running into the same problem in 2020 with dart sass. Seems to be correct that it doesn't watch any file paths that involve going above the folder the file being watched is. Thanks!

Comment: underrated answer. i came across the same problem, where I was importing scss files above the current directory. In that case --watch flag didn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

```
interface FileImporter {
  findFileUrl(
    url: string,
    options: {fromImport: boolean}
  ): FileImporterResult | null;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.